# How can one time out a root shell after a certain period of time?

Tags: bash, ksh

Is there a way to 'time out' a root shell (for example, in `gnome-terminal`) so that after a certain amount of time not issuing any commands, the shell exits?

I'm searching for a solution that works in `bash` on Fedora, and in `ksh` on OpenBSD.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can set set the `TMOUT` variable to a number in seconds that you wish for bash to wait before automatically logging out the shell if no command is run.

Comment: TMOUT is available both with bash and ksh.

Comment: @camh Zsh too, I would expect any modern shell to support it.

Comment: It's a great thing that I learned today.

Comment: `echo 'export TMOUT=72000; readonly TMOUT # 20 minutes logout' >> /root/.bashrc`

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is in regards to Bash & Ksh. But I thought I would post something similar for csh/tcsh, for the record.

On FreeBSD, the default shell is tcsh. You can auto logout a session using the `autologout` feature of the tcsh shell.

The following will autologout a session after one minute of idle activity.

```
freebsd82# set -r autologout=’1′
(Wait one minute)
freebsd82# auto-logout
Connection to freebsd82 closed.
```

The [tcsh(1)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=tcsh&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%208.2-RELEASE&format=html) manpage describes it like this:

> ```
> autologout (+)
>      The first word is the number of minutes  of  inactivity  before
>      automatic  logout.   The  optional second word is the number of
>      minutes of inactivity before automatic locking.  When the shell
>      automatically logs out, it prints `auto-logout', sets the vari-
>      able logout to `automatic' and exits.  When the shell automati-
>      cally locks, the user is required to enter his password to con-
>      tinue working.  Five incorrect  attempts  result  in  automatic
>      logout.  Set to `60' (automatic logout after 60 minutes, and no
>      locking) by default in login and superuser shells, but  not  if
>      the shell thinks it is running under a window system (i.e., the
>      DISPLAY environment variable is set), the tty is  a  pseudo-tty
>      (pty)  or  the shell was not so compiled (see the version shell
>      variable).  See also the afsuser and logout shell variables.
> ```