# How to terminate an interactive ssh session after certain amount of time

Tags: linux, ssh, sshd

In my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file I have set the below parameters:

```
ClientAliveInterval 10
ClientAliveCountMax 3
```

Now from host machine I did `ssh` to the my server (where I made changes to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`) file. After that I restarted the `ssh` sevices by running:

```
/etc/init.d/sshd reload
```

I am expecting the `ssh` connection should be disconnected after 30 seconds but it keeps on than there for almost an hour now.

Can anybody let me know what is going wrong here?

I am using OpenSSH version 6.1.

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](http://serverfault.com/questions/559424/setting-up-clientalivecountmax-and-clientaliveinterval-is-not-working-as-expecte). The AliveInterval is something you use to keep connections open, not to close them.

Comment: Thanks Mat but This page says http://www.manpagez.com/man/5/sshd_config/.If ClientAliveInterval (see below) is set to 15, and ClientAliveCountMax is left at the default, unresponsive SSH clients will be disconnected after approximately 45 seconds.  This option applies to protocol version 2 only and we left our ssh conection idle for almost half an hour

Comment: "... unresponsive ..." is the key word there.

Comment: @Mat when I use this setting ClientAliveInterval 10
ClientAliveCountMax 0 and left ssh connection idle ,it just closed after 10 seconds.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Disconnect users after 30 seconds no matter what they are doing?

Answer (score 5):

I do not think you can get what you want using ssh settings. `ClientAlive*` settings are meant for when the connection between the ssh client and the ssh server become unresponsive, how long either side should wait (these are obviously the client's timeouts).

Rather I'd use Bash's `$TMOUT` environment variable to get the shell to disconnect after a set period of time.

```
TMOUT  If  set  to  a  value greater than zero, TMOUT is treated as the 
       default timeout for the read builtin.  The select command terminates 
       if input does not arrive after TMOUT seconds when input is  coming  
       from  a  terminal.   In  an interactive  shell,  the value is 
       interpreted as the number of seconds to wait for input after issuing 
       the primary prompt.  Bash terminates after waiting for that number of 
       seconds if input does not arrive.
```

#### References

- [How can one time out a root shell after a certain period of time?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12719/how-can-one-time-out-a-root-shell-after-a-certain-period-of-time/12721#12721)