# What is the default idle timeout for OpenSSH?

Tags: ssh, centos, openssh

I can't seem to find an answer to this simple question, which I need for some compliance documentation.

On a default install of CentOS 6.5 (OpenSSH 5.3p1-94.el6), after how long of being idle will a user's SSH session be terminated?  I believe the following can be set to increase the idle timeout, but they are commented out by default.

```
$ grep -i alive /etc/ssh/sshd_config
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
```

Also, is there a command to dump a list of the current `sshd` settings?  I don't see anything in `man sshd`.

Comment: Some shells can be set to exit after a timeout. That would cause the ssh session to terminate. Check whether your TMOUT environment variable is set.

Answer (score 33):

The commented lines in `sshd_config` usually display the defaults. This is the case with all of the lines in your question. You can verify this in the [`sshd_config` manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config). Here are the relevant snippets:

> **`TCPKeepAlive`**
>
>     Specifies whether the system should send TCP keepalive messages to the other side.  If they are sent, death of the
>     connection or crash of one of the machines will be properly noticed.  However, this means that connections will die
>     if the route is down temporarily, and some people find it annoying.  On the other hand, if TCP keepalives are not
>     sent, sessions may hang indefinitely on the server, leaving “ghost” users and consuming server resources.
>
> The default is “yes” (to send TCP keepalive messages), and the server will notice if the network goes down or the
> client host crashes.  This avoids infinitely hanging sessions.
>
> To disable TCP keepalive messages, the value should be set to “no”.
>
> This option was formerly called `KeepAlive`.

> **`ClientAliveCountMax`**
>
>     Sets the number of client alive messages (see below) which may be sent without
>     [sshd(8)](https://github.com/metacloud/openssh/blob/master/sshd.0)
>     receiving any messages back
>     from the client.  If this threshold is reached while client alive messages are being sent, sshd will disconnect the
>     client, terminating the session.  It is important to note that the use of client alive messages is very different
>     from
>     **`TCPKeepAlive`**
>     <del>(below)</del>
>     (above).  The client alive messages are sent through the encrypted channel and therefore will not
>     be spoofable.  The TCP keepalive option enabled by
>     **`TCPKeepAlive`**
>     is spoofable.  The client alive mechanism is
>     valuable when the client or server depend on knowing when a connection has become inactive.
>
> The default value is 3.  If **`ClientAliveInterval`** (see below) is set to 15, and **`ClientAliveCountMax`** is left at the
> default, unresponsive SSH clients will be disconnected after approximately 45 seconds.  This option applies to protocol version 2 only.

> **`ClientAliveInterval`**
>
>     Sets a timeout interval in seconds after which if no data has been received from the client,
>     [sshd(8)](https://github.com/metacloud/openssh/blob/master/sshd.0)
>     will send a
>     message through the encrypted channel to request a response from the client.  The default is 0, indicating that
>     these messages will not be sent to the client.  This option applies to protocol version 2 only.

Comment: Correct me if wrong, but if there was no firewall in between me and the machine (w/ default configs), then I'd never be disconnected?  I know our firewall drops idle TCP connections after 60 minutes, so that's where the closing idle connections is happening.  I just wanted to check and see if OpenSSH itself explicitly closes sessions.  I think the answer is No, openssh does not explicitly close idle connections, but firewalls *typically* do.  The settings mentioned in your answer actually help to persist the connection or to properly terminate the session if it sees it's been dropped.

Comment: The quoted text says that the default for ClientAliveInterval is 0, which means that it doesn't define a time interval for which a connection stays open. And yet we know that the time interval has some finite value by default. Therefore it seems that there must be some *other* parameter that sets how long the connection stays open by default. If my analysis above is correct, then suppose both server and client are linux machines running openssh, and both are using all the defaults. In this case which side sets the default, what is its value, and where is it set?

Comment: @BenCrowell *And yet we know that the time interval has some finite value by default.* What *time interval* and how do you know this?

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost: just connect to any machine with default settings and no firewalls, let it idle, and it will eventually drop by inactivity. I've never measured how long it takes, but I've seen such idle disconnection occurs.

Comment: Nothing in this answer seems to indicate that SSH would terminate due to idleness.

Answer (score 19):

OpenSSH will not terminate a shell session that has been idle for some time.  This is not something that OpenSSH does. Terminating an idle shell session is unrelated to the configuration of OpenSSH.

The settings that you are showing are related to timeouts when the connection goes down and are unrelated to the shell on the remote host and what the user is doing or not doing there.

The remote host's shell may terminate (or may get killed by some other process) after some time of idleness, but this is unrelated to the configuration of the SSH service on the server and of your SSH client.

Related:

- [How to terminate an interactive ssh session after certain amount of time](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103828) (mentions the `TMOUT` shell variable, which may be responsible for terminating an idle `bash` shell).

---

To dump the `sshd` configuration, use the "extended test mode" as root:

```
sshd -T
```

This is documented in [the `sshd(8)` manual](http://man.openbsd.org/sshd) (looking at `OpenSSH_7.7, LibreSSL 2.7.2` on OpenBSD here):

> `-T`
>
> Extended test mode.  Check the validity of the configuration
>                file, **output the effective configuration to stdout and then exit**.
>                Optionally, Match rules may be applied by specifying the
>                connection parameters using one or more `-C` options.

This option was added to `sshd` for OpenSSH 5.1/5.1p1 in 2008.

Comment: _OpenSSH will not terminate a shell session that has been idle for some time. This  is not something that OpenSSH does. Terminating an idle shell session is  unrelated to the configuration of OpenSSH._

Actually this doesn't appear to be true.  If `ClientAliveCountMax` is set to `0`, an idle connection will be terminated after `ClientAliveInterval` seconds have passed.  I haven't been able to find any documentation to support this behaviour though, which is frustrating... anyone?

Comment: Also mentioned in JohnA's answer, not sure why that one was downvoted.

Comment: @Annihilannic The connection would probably be terminated, but SSH would not explicitly terminate the shell session, which is what I'm emphasizing in my answer. If, for example, a shell session is running in `tmux` or `screen`, and SSH terminates the connection (for whatever reason), you will find that the _shell session_ does not terminate.  If `tmux` or `screen` is not used, the shell session will most likely be sent a `HUP` signal and terminate, but it is not SSH that sends that `HUP` signal.  SSH will _not_ terminate shell sessions.

Comment: "*SSH will not terminate shell sessions.*" Isn't that a rather **fine point** considering that for at least some (headless) hosts, losing the SSH *connection* is tantamount to losing the shell (e.g. `bash`) session? Also - the OP specifically asked about `SSH session`?

Comment: wait, if SSH won't terminate idle sessions (be it client or server-side), why there's such thing as `ServerAliveInterval` on `~/.ssh/config`??? lol

Comment: @igorsantos07 It's probably there because you put it in that file. What do you mean by "idle" here? That setting is available to detect _unusable_ networks or dead connections. Using that setting, the session would not be idle in the sense of no data being passed between client and server, unless the network suddenly became unusable, for example due to a physical break or because the server died.

Comment: Hopefully @annihilannic has seen the answer from andrew saying that AliveCountMax == 0 was deemed a bug, meaning I can get behind this answer after all

Answer (score 16):

You can set up SSH keepalive for either the client or server side:

#### Client side

File: `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`

Content:

```
Host *
ServerAliveInterval XX
ServerAliveCountMax YY
```

#### Server side

File: `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Content:

```
ClientAliveInterval XX
ClientAliveCountMax YY
```

Extracted from: http://www.sysadmit.com/2016/02/linux-y-vmware-ssh-evitar-desconexion.html

Comment: Useful, but doesn't answer the question in any way.

Comment: @bzeaman: To be fair, none of the proposals here answer the question: *"What is the default idle timeout for OpenSSH?"*

Answer (score 6):

If the requirement is to close the SSH connection after a period of inactivity, the shells themselves provide timeout variables.

For bash:

> TMOUT:  If  set  to  a  value greater than zero, TMOUT is treated as
>   the 
>          default timeout for the read builtin.  The select command terminates 
>          if input does not arrive after TMOUT seconds when input is  coming from  a  terminal.   In  an interactive  shell,  the value is 
>          interpreted as the number of seconds to wait for input after issuing 
>          the primary prompt.  Bash terminates after waiting for that number of 
>          seconds if input does not arrive.

test this by running `TMOUT=10` and wait for 10 sec to close the connection.

For tcsh:

> The autologout shell variable can be set to log out or lock the shell
>   after a given number of minutes of inactivity.

In tcsh, the syntax for setting the timeout for ten *minutes* is `set autologout=10`. This doesn't work in the original csh.

Answer (score 5):

SSH no longer has an idle timeout, but you can likely use the [shell `TMOUT` variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/437333/27685) instead. Mark  it `readonly` to prevent tampering.

SSH does have keep-alive settings, on both the client and server,
but they’re not idle timeouts. They can be used to automatically detect and close non-responsive connections. And they can also do the opposite of an idle timeout: send fake traffic back and forth at regular intervals so that firewalls don’t expire idle connections.

In older versions of SSH, if `ClientAliveCountMax=0`, that *would* end the SSH session after `ClientAliveInterval` seconds of inactivity, but that wasn’t documented or intentional on the part of OpenSSH developers.

```
# Will time out idle sessions, but only if OpenSSH version < 8.2, e.g., CentOS 7
ClientAliveInterval 60
ClientAliveCountMax 0
```

This was viewed as a bug in sshd, and [removed in OpenSSH 8.2](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/commit/69334996ae203c51c70bf01d414c918a44618f8e). Now `ClientAliveCountMax=0` means to disable the client-alive stuff, not expire idle sessions. See the [bug report](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2627).

Answer (score -1):

If you want the timeout to be 10 seconds for everyone, do the following for the server config (sshd_config):

```
ClientAliveInterval 10
ClientAliveCountMax 0
```

If you want the timeout to be 10 seconds for local clients, do the following for the client config (ssh_config):

```
ServerAliveInterval 10
ServerAliveCountMax 0
```

If the AliveCountMax parameter is non-zero, it probably won't work because the server will reply resetting the timer (unless there's a connection problem).  You can see this by running the ssh client with debugging turned on.

Comment: doesn't answer the actual question

Comment: It gets close enough for me, but note @andrew says, with a compelling citation, that the AliveCountMax == 0 behavior was deemed a bug

Answer (score -1):

you can increase the session time when making a connection like:

```
ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=60 -i Firstme.pem ec2-user@3.90.84.197
```

`-o ServerAliveInterval=60` here you can define your time in minutes, 60, 120,...

Comment: that's actually _minutes_. And anyway, it doesn't answer the actual question at all